Site still changes content despite restricting history.pushState
[Not sure why this question is marked as duplicate with question that asks about executing of page variables through chrome extension, what I am trying to ask is pretty different issue, my question is how to effectively stop dynamic rendering of the site and related to it]
I'm developing a chrome-extension scraper for a site. What we do is that we simply retrieve the content on the page whenever a certain button is clicked on the site.
Now the site uses the state concepts. What it does is that as soon as button is clicked, it starts rendering the content and change the URL without reloading the page.
What my end goal is that whenever that button is clicked, the new content or the URL should be loaded in an iframe but the current site state should not be changed at all, that's all I want.
I tried below soltuion
history.pushState = function(e) {      return;  }
But all of the time it changes the content.
I've tried the MutationObserver way as well but it just freezes the site.
What else options are available for me?

Why do you need to load the page in an iframe if you're just retrieving the content?

So suppose there are 8 pages, I'm on second page and I click the button to retrieve the content, what happens is that it will render the content on the page but now to go to the next button, I would have to do.
1- Go back to the previous page ether through history popstate method or back button.
2- Go to the exact page number I was previously on and then attempt to click the next button.
This whole process consumes time. I am only trying to reduce the time consumption through method of iframe.

Are you able to get the page URLs of each of the next pages and load iframes for those?

Actually the URL, is pretty generic, it doesn't work as such, even if I try to open the URL in new tab, it would just simply take me to the beginning of state 0 or the home page.

You should be able add a click event listener to the button that handles the event as it's being captured and then stop the click event propagation in the handler, like so:
button.addEventListener("click", e => {
    // do whatever else you want to do here
    
    // stop the event from propagating (and bubbling)
    e.stopPropagation();
}, {capture: true});

This works because an event first gets 'captured', walking down the DOM tree to the button, triggering all the capture listeners before it 'bubbles' back up to the root element, triggering all the regular event listeners.
Also: restricting pushState can't do anything about the site changing itself, it'll only ever prevent it from setting a new entry in your browsing history.

Problem is that I want the JS scripts to run, like the link or the fetch calls need to be made by the scripts that are triggered by the click event of that button. I only do not want to render the content on current page like somehow prevent the current site to load any content.

I don't think that is generally possible, since the site might be doing a lot of things to render that content, and I don't think there's ways to stop them all.
MutationObserver might be your best bet. My guess for why it's freezing the site is that if you cause more mutations inside the observer, you've probably made an infinite loop and need some sort of exit condition to that. But even a MutationObserver won't help you if the site adds new event listeners or so, so you might be putting the page in a very broken state.
